# Setting ClaimTypes.Name does not result in an identity.name

Tags: c#, .net, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm playing around with claimbaised authorization in .net 4.5  . This works pretty fine. But I got a hopefully small problem.

I thought that setting the name claim type should result in a identity name

I checked that ident.NameClaimType has the same value as ClaimTypes.Name
Both are http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name

I set the new claim. Which i can see is part of the identity claims.
but Identity.Name is still empty.

what am I doing wrong?

```
  ClaimsIdentity ident = (ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity;

  ident.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, resourceName));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when my claims identity had not `AuthenticationType` set. Once I have passed in an `AuthenticationType` in the `ClaimsIdentity` constructor it worked.

Comment: Yeah seems like this was the problem